# What is wrong with my snap to grid code?

Tags: python, graphics, grid

First of all, I'm fairly sure snapping to grid is fairly easy, however I've run into some odd trouble in this situation and my maths are too weak to work out specifically what is wrong.

Here's the situation

I have an abstract concept of a grid, with Y steps exactly Y_STEP apart (the x steps are working fine so ignore them for now)

The grid is in an abstract coordinate space, and to get things to line up I've got a magic offset in there, let's call it Y_OFFSET

to snap to the grid I've got the following code (python)

```
def snapToGrid(originalPos, offset, step):
    index = int((originalPos - offset) / step) #truncates the remainder away
    return index * gap + offset
```

so I pass the cursor position, Y_OFFSET and Y_STEP into that function and it returns me the nearest floored y position on the grid

That appears to work fine in the original scenario, however when I take into account the fact that the view is scrollable things get a little weird.

Scrolling is made as basic as I can get it, I've got a viewPort that keeps count of the distance scrolled along the Y Axis and just offsets everything that goes through it.

Here's a snippet of the cursor's mouseMotion code:

```
def mouseMotion(self, event):
    pixelPos = event.pos[Y]
    odePos = Scroll.pixelPosToOdePos(pixelPos)
    self.tool.positionChanged(odePos)
```

So there's two things to look at there, first the Scroll module's translation from pixel position to the abstract coordinate space, then the tool's positionChanged function which takes the abstract coordinate space value and snaps to the nearest Y step.

Here's the relevant Scroll code

```
def pixelPosToOdePos(pixelPos):
    offsetPixelPos = pixelPos - self.viewPortOffset
    return pixelsToOde(offsetPixelPos)

def pixelsToOde(pixels):
    return float(pixels) / float(pixels_in_an_ode_unit)
```

And the tools update code

```
def positionChanged(self, newPos):
    self.snappedPos = snapToGrid(originalPos, Y_OFFSET, Y_STEP)
```

The last relevant chunk is when the tool goes to render itself.  It goes through the Scroll object, which transforms the tool's snapped coordinate space position into an onscreen pixel position, here's the code:

```
#in Tool
def render(self, screen):
    Scroll.render(screen, self.image, self.snappedPos)

#in Scroll
def render(self, screen, image, odePos):
    pixelPos = self.odePosToPixelPos(odePos)
    screen.blit(image, pixelPos) # screen is a surface from pygame for the curious

def odePosToPixelPos(self.odePos):
    offsetPos = odePos + self.viewPortOffset
    return odeToPixels(offsetPos)

def odeToPixels(odeUnits):
    return int(odeUnits * pixels_in_an_ode_unit)
```

Whew, that was a long explanation.  Hope you're still with me...

The problem I'm now getting is that when I scroll up the drawn image loses alignment with the cursor.
It starts snapping to the Y step exactly 1 step below the cursor.
Additionally it appears to phase in and out of allignment.
At some scrolls it is out by 1 and other scrolls it is spot on.
It's never out by more than 1 and it's always snapping to a valid grid location.

Best guess I can come up with is that somewhere I'm truncating some data in the wrong spot, but no idea where or how it ends up with this behavior.

Anyone familiar with coordinate spaces, scrolling and snapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm answering my own question here, as alexk mentioned, using int to truncate was my mistake.

The behaviour I'm after is best modeled by math.floor().

Apologies, the original question does not contain enough information to really work out what the problem is.  I didn't have the extra bit of information at that point.

With regards to the typo note, I think I may be using the context in a confusing manner...  From the perspective of the positionChanged() function, the parameter is a new position coming in.
From the perspective of the snapToGrid() function the parameter is an original position which is being changed to a snapped position.
The language is like that because part of it is in my event handling code and the other part is in my general services code.  I should have changed it for the example

Comment: Glad you fixed it. Just FYI, you don't have to create a new post each time you have an update, you can just edit your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a typo in positionChanged() ?

```
def positionChanged(self, newPos):
    self.snappedPos = snapToGrid(newPos, Y_OFFSET, Y_STEP)
```

I guess you are off by one pixel because of the accuracy problems during float division. Try changing your snapToGrid() to this:

```
def snapToGrid(originalPos, offset, step):
    EPS = 1e-6
    index = int((originalPos - offset) / step  + EPS) #truncates the remainder away
    return index * gap + offset
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, there may be a typo, but I can't see it...

Unfortunately the change to snapToGrid didn't make a difference, so I don't think that's the issue.

It's not off by one pixel, but rather it's off by Y_STEP.  Playing around with it some more I've found that I can't get it to be exact at any point that the screen is scrolled up and also that it happens towards the top of the screen, which I suspect is ODE position zero, so I'm guessing my problem is around small or negative values.

Comment: Regarding the typo, you are passing `originalPos` instead of `newPos` to `snapToGrid()`.

As for the negative values, could it be related to the fact that int(-1.5) == -1 ?